# Efficient way of storing dictionary in pandas

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

Given an dataframe filled with zeros of type string as shown -

```
df = pd.DataFrame("0",index=range(5),columns=["Content","Val"])
```

**Problem** - It is needed to add a dictionary to `Val` column.
**My solution** - Insert dictionary as a form of string and then convert it back to dictionary format using `ast.literal_eval` for any modification and then again save it as string as shown.

```
# saving a dictionary to Val column
df.iloc[0,1] = df.iloc[0,1].replace("0",str({"k1":12, "k2":55}))
# converting to dict. format for any modification 
extracted_dict = ast.literal_eval(df.iloc[0,1])
```

**Question** - Can there be any other method of achieving the same or can this method be improved?

Comment: Why would you want to store dictionaries in a dataframe in the first place?

Comment: Suppose I have a subject `Mathematics` stored in `Content`, then need is to get the number of time distinct students appeared for the exam of mathematics. So, dictionary seems to me a legitimate way of storing such information like `Sam:5, Jack:2`. Also, I've a huge data so relying on the efficiency of pandas. @jpp What are your views on this? Can there be a better way!

Comment: `pandas` is definitely **not** efficient for holding dataframes. In fact, it just adds overhead. `pandas` works best with contiguous-memory arrays (e.g. `int`, `float`). Your best bet is to restructure your solution to avoid `pandas`.